# kafka http sink connector regex.patterns/regex.replacements

Tags: http, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am enabling an http sink connector with multipe kafka topics. I would like to use kafka's templating url feature with regex find and replace

the url form would be as follows

```
example.com/{$topic}
```

the topic would be of form:

```
this-is-the-topic-name
```

i would like to change it to

```
this_is_the_topic_name
```

final url would be come :

```
example.com/this_is_the_topic_name
```

This does not work. Any ideas on how to get this working?

the config is:
Regular expression patterns `[-]`

Regular expression replacements `_`

Comment: You need a custom SMT to do this. RegexRouter does not do string replacement. And Confluent Cloud, for example, may not support Custom SMT